# Как сделать изменение спрайта кнопки по её нажатию?

Tags: c#, unity3d, button, спрайт

Мне нужно сделать кнопку по нажатию которой она меняет спрайт а если нажать опять измениться обратно!

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы это сделать надо создать **Canvas**. Нажми два раза на Canvas и тогда будет видна полная область канваса. В области канваса будет находится все связанное с UI это кнопки, ползунки, текст и так далее.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После этого в **Canvas** нужно добавить **Button**(находится также в вкладке UI). Появится кнопка переместите и увеличите ее как вам надо. Если хотите изменить текст то в Button есть компонент Text. В этом компоненте вы сможете изменить текст кнопки[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Создаем спрайт[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И создаем скрипт и пишем следующий код:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{
public Sprite[] S;
private int pos;
public SpriteRenderer SR;

public void Click()
{
    pos++;
}

private void Update()
{
    if (pos >= S.Length)
        pos = 0;
    else
        SR.sprite = S[pos];
}
}
```

Объяснение кода:

**S** - это массив с нашими двумя спрайтами

**SR** - это SpriteRenderer это компонент у спрайта

**pos** - это переменная указывает на каком спрайте по счету находится наш объект

Когда на кнопку нажали то выполняется функция `Click()` и она добавляет 1 к pos. В фeнкции `Update()` мы в зависимости от позиции берем из массива нужный нам спрайт и если спрайты закончились то мы возвращаемся к начальной картинке. Данный скрипт можно использовать не только на двух картинках ,но и на больших количествах картинок.

После чего добавляем скрипт куда хотим(желательно в Main Camera). В скрипте указываем наши картинки и добавляем SpriteRenderer. Затем заходим в Button и в параметре void Click() добавляем наш объект куда мы положили скрипт и выбираем  скрипт а в нем функцию `Click()`[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Зачем здесь апдейт?

Comment: Я хотел чтоб сама кнопка изменяла цвет, но за скрипт спасибо пригодиться. Можешь сделать с кнопкой?