# Как изменить изображение кнопки при нажатии на неё?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Нужно изменить картинку у кнопки при нажатии на неё.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1407659/373567

Comment: Спасибо большое.)

Comment: Не совсем то, что мне нужно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Реализация:**

Добавить к вашему обьекту где нужно изменять спрайт (картинку) компонент Button если он не добавлен, создать и добавить в этот обьект скрипт (или расширить текущий если он есть) содержащий следующий код:

```
    using UnityEngine;
    using UnityEngine.UI; // для использования Button
    
    [RequireComponent(typeof(Button))] 
     // это своего рода гарантия что Button присутсвует на данном обьекте, 
     // необходим для присваивания _button через GetComponent<Button>()
    public class ButtonSpriteChanger : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private Button _button;
    
        private void Awake()
        {
            _button = GetComponent<Button>();
        }
    
        public void ChangeButtonSprite(Sprite sprite)
        {
            _button.image.sprite = sprite; 
            // обращение к кнопке, ее компоненту Image затем к его спрайту, 
            // и изменить на наш отправленный параметр
        }
    }
```

**Использование:**

Через инспектор, делается так как описал выше, добавляете данный скрипт к вашей кнопке, далее потянув за ее название перетащить ее в OnClick() вашей кнопки как показано на скриншоте, затем выбрать из списка справа созданный метод (в моем случае ChangeButtonSprite) и после чего в появившемся маленьком окне можно выбрать спрайт на который он должен измениться. Всё, можно использовать!

[image: Использование_1]

Через код, можно использовать в любом другом коде, для этого должна быть ссылка на эту кнопку, после чего по этой ссылке можно обратиться к созданному скрипту и использовать созданный метод, код:

```
_button.GetComponent<ButtonSpriteChanger>().ChangerButtonSprite(_sprite);
```

Здесь больше ньюансов, во-первых по ссылке `_button` обязательно должен быть прикреплен созданный нами компонент `ButtonSpriteChanger`, и `_sprite` должен быть определен в инспекторе, или другим способом.